# Webpack/React: Following egghead.io tutorial but getting an error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've just started following [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-react-fundamentals-development-environment-setup?series=react-fundamentals#/tab-code) tutorial.

I've gone through the first video three or four times now. When I try to run the application, I get the following error in the console:

```
ERROR in ./main.js
Module parse failed: /Users/newuser/projects/js101/react-egghead/main.js Unexpected token (5:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:16)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/newuser/projects/js101/react-egghead/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:920:13)
...
```

I've looked at similar questions on SO but none seem to have an answer for me.

Here's my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3333
    },
    moudle: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is what package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "react-egghead",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

And, although it's not mentioned in the video, I've added a .babelrc file: (which I have now removed)

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

This is where the parse fails (line 5):

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App.js'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I really don't know what to try next. Is it a problem with my environment set up or is it a problem with the code in main.js?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are using stage-0 preset but you have not installed it, that could be the problem.

Comment: The error column points to the ```<``` JSX tag, so it looks like jsx is the problem, maybe for the reason @QoP said. ES6 imports seem to be parsed correctly. Also, if you use a babelrc file I'd avoid passing query params to the loader as it may be confusing, one place overriding configs from the other.

Comment: I've removed stage-0 from .babelrc. I've also tried specifying 'babel-loader' as the loader instead of 'babel'. The problem persists.

Comment: I've removed .babelrc completely. It wasn't mentioned in the tutorial but I thought it might solve the problem. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your webpack config. Instead of `module` you typed `moudle`, so your loader configs are actually ignored by webpack :)